# Aframe repetition of animations?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am wondering how to repeat animations. I have made this:

```
  var drip_stage = 0; 

  function Drip(){

    var water = $(".water");//water drop

    water.attr('position', '-4.4 8.45 3.95');// faucet position
    
   //if statements for all stages of water

    if (drip_stage==0){

        water.attr('animation',"property: position; to:-4.1 5.1 3.95; dur: 5000;");

       drip_stage++

    }// other statements

    water.attr('visible','true');

    console.log("repeat");

    setTimeout(Drip, 5000);//repeat



  }

  AFRAME.registerComponent("drip",{

    init: Drip

  });
```

I am wondering if there is a to repeat the animation but at different times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [loop property](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html#api_loop) to `true`:

```
animation="property: position; from: 0 4.25 -10; to: 0 -2.25 -10; dur: 1000; loop: true"
```

[Glitch illustrating](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spectacular-sophisticated-petalite?path=index.html%3A12%3A104)

Comment: I don't want it to loop. I want it to be timed repeated, so like stage 1 has no drip, stage 2 has drip, stage 3 and 4 doesn't have drip, etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by drip. It needs runnable code / image to illustrate.